# Mellanox ConnectX-7 - BW average drops from 395Gb/s to 248Gb/s in ib_write_bw test

Tags: infiniband, mellanox

I have two machines connected by two ConnectX-7 to each other.

When running ib_write_bw test, the BW average starts from 395Gb/s, which is very good. But the speed drops very fast to less than 250Gb/s.

[pci status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM0eM.png)
[test log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Vep.png)

Answer (score 0):

The CPU frequency is decreasing with each line shown in the test log.

Maybe you could try to set a more aggressive CPU frequency governor on both servers to prevent it ?

You can use `mlnx_tune` utility to generate a report that might help you finding the problem (I guess it's installed within Mellanox OFED), such as :
`mlnx_tune --report`

To globally improve performance over Mellanox hardware, you can have a look at the [Mellanox Support ToolKit](https://support.mellanox.com/s/article/MLNX2-117-2246kn) that will give you a bunch of tools to understand and address performance issues.

Comment: Now I think maybe it is because CPU is not powerful enough. By using htop, the CPU assigned with task is running 100%. The cpu is xeon gold 6430 and scaling_max_freq is 1901000.

Comment: I think the CPU if powerful enough. Are you sure the BIOS performance and thermal  settings are not set to something like power saving ?

Comment: Yes, I used this script https://gist.github.com/jynik/9907605 to make scaling governor to 'performance'

Comment: I mean the BIOS settings, the one controlling the server hardware, not the operating system. I've had some trouble with it while setting up HDR InfiniBand when BIOS was configured with power saving options.